# Wubi does not start in win7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, wubi

I have win7 64 bit and wish to install ubuntu 12.04 via wubi. Seemingly I  am unable to run wubi installer.

1. Made  wubi installer as vista compatible.
2. Put the  iso & wubi in the same folder.
3. Tried  using the `--force` method.

In the log file it says to look for kubuntu alternate cd  & cannot find it

Maybe python variable are active or how could i delete them.

Any help - much appreciated

Comment: Post the log file or pastebin it so we can see.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of wubi is compatible with windows 7. So no need to change the comparability.

- Get latest wubi [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) (For installation of 12.04).
- Download correct version of ubuntu.

More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

ubuntu download links → http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I HAVE DOWNLOADED THE CORRECT VERSION - EVEN DONE MD5 HASH ALSO. BUT EVEN THEN IT DOES NOT START AT ALL

I HAVE HAD LINUXMINT MINT4WIN INSTALLER FOR MINT 12 - IT WORKED PROPERLY. BUT NOT THIS WUBI.

Comment: can you please turn off CAPS LOCK ? Note that you need a DESKTOP CD ISO. A DVD ISO may not work. Alternate ISO files are not supported. Which file have you downloaded? 32bit version or 64bit version?

Comment: its 32 & 64 bit desktop iso. got wubi as well.

as i told you in the log file in temps directory it seems to look for kubuntu alternate 64 bit cd iso.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced a similar problem but I figured out what's wrong

What I did was checked the temp dir(`run>temp`) and checked the logs file with notepad.
(and recently found that WUBI checks iso file(any) in your hard disk)

In my case there was a iso file in my drive (`E:/matrix_path_of_neo.iso`) and WUBI tried to consider it as an Ubuntu iso.(I don't now if its a kind of bug)

I simply just renamed the file format of the file which was in E drive (`.iso` to `.iso1`)
and this solves my problem as WUBI does not recognised it as a iso file.

So if you try to check the log file and read out the errors and try to solve it as I mentioned above this will work 100% of the time from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

finaly solved the issue

1) cleared all temps directory & process locked files
2) disconnected internet
3) made sure that no wubi or ubuntu iso are on the HD.
4) mounted the ISO and used the --force method

and it worked.

Finally!!

A friend of mine also said to me wubi works on XP with disconnected internet.. Is this a bug